# Combination of a column based on another one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have not found a question about this precise task, so I'd like to ask how to reach this result in R.
I have this dataframe in R.

```
or<-c("1","1","1","2","2")
pr<-c("a","b","c","w","x")
c<-data.frame(or,pr)
```

Here the result:

```
 c
       or pr
    1   1  a
    2   1  b
    3   1  c
    4   2  w
    5   2  x
```

I'd like to have the -not double, i.e. not aa,bb,cc,xx,ww- combinations of the column `pr`, based on the column `or`. The result is something like:

```
d
first second
a     b
b     a
c     b
b     c
c     a
a     c
w     x
x     w
```

The first 6 rows are the combinations of the `pr` occurrencies with `or=1`, and the 7th and 8th row are the combinations of row with `or=2`.

I've found the function

```
expand.grid(c$pr)
```

But it does not work, above all it does not put the combinations in the frame of 2 column I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CJ` from `data.table` with column `or` as the group variable:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(c)[, CJ(pr, pr), or][V1 != V2, .(first = V1, second = V2)]

#   first second
#1:     a      b
#2:     a      c
#3:     b      a
#4:     b      c
#5:     c      a
#6:     c      b
#7:     w      x
#8:     x      w
```

*Update*:

If you prefer a base R solution, you can use `tapply()` with `expand.grid()`:

```
setNames(
    do.call(rbind, c(make.row.names = F, 
        tapply(c$pr, c$or, FUN = function(v) subset(expand.grid(v, v), Var1 != Var2)))), 
    c('first', 'second'))

#  first second
#1     b      a
#2     c      a
#3     a      b
#4     c      b
#5     a      c
#6     b      c
#7     x      w
#8     w      x
```

Comment: Hi this is fantastic, thanks! Is it possible to have the same things without using that package and apply some internal function (i.e. not from an external package) of R?

Comment: You can use `tapply()` (which provides grouped operation) and `expand.grid()` in base R, see the update.